# How to validate the mail in the server side

Tags: asp.net, ajax, regex, validation, email-validation

How to validate Email in server side . I know how to do that in client side but what about the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Validation-by-Function/aspRegularExpressionValidatorforemailaddressC.htm):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
        id="regEmail"
        ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
        Text="(Invalid email)"
        ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
        Runat="server" />
```

As far as the regular expression to use, just pick one that suits your needs.

Comment: then how to validate only in server side?

Comment: @just_name, the RegularExpressionValidator control validates on the server side. IIRC there is an option where you could have it emit client side validation as well, but it will at least validate on the server.

Comment: Set `EnableClientScript` property to false in validator.

Comment: because i will validate under some condition(check box ). if true then validate and compare validation to confirm the mail if not disable the textbox and then no validation.

Comment: @just_name, in this case you could use the CustomValidator control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx and apply the Regex manually on the server if the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

```
 String mail = "YYY@imail.com";
 string expression = @"^[a-z][a-z|0-9|]*([_][a-z|0-9]+)*([.][a-z|" +@"0-9]+([_][a-z|0-9]+)*)?@[a-z][a-z|0-9|]*\.([a-z]" +@"[a-z|0-9]*(\.[a-z][a-z|0-9]*)?)$";

            Match match = Regex.Match(mail, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (match.Success)
                Response.Write("VALID EMAIL");
                else
                 Response.Write("INVALID EMAIL");
            return;
```